# How to remove Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}' in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How to remove Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'?

Here's my code snippet:

```
//component      
  const SearchResults = ({ results }: { results: {} }) => {
  let pageCount = results?.length ? results?.length / 6 : 0;
// jsx
```

Note that the results prop is an API result that contains an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly defining the type of *results* as an object.
You can temporarily define the type as *any* and add the required type later on.

```
 const SearchResults = ({ results }: any ) => {
  let pageCount = results?.length ? results?.length / 6 : 0;
```